# Showing 6x6 matrices are similar and finding the dimension of the nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

Let $S$ be the set of 6x6 matrices with rational coefficients such that the characteristic polynomial is $x^6-x^2$ and the minimal polynomial is $x^5-x$. Problem: Given $A\in S$ what is the dimension of the null space of $(A^2+1)^2$.

Any two elements of $S$ have the same invariant factors so they're similar. The characteristic polynomial factors into $x^2(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$ over the rationals. So $0,0,1,-1$ will be diagonal entries of $A$.

1. What are the other diagonal entries?
2. How does $(A^2+1)^2$ correspond to the minimal polynomial of $A$?
3. How can I determine if there will be a 1 on the subdiagonal corresponding to the double root 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure what you mean by "invariant factors".  I haven't heard of any such thing that would be helpful in this context.

You can consider matrices in $S$ as matrices in the *algebraic completion* of $\Bbb Q$, so that the polynomial completely factors.  So, we can write
$$
x^6 - x^2 = x^2(x-1)(x+1)(x-i)(x+i)
$$
where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

Now, it is important to note that $A$ is diagonalizable.  So, $A^2 + I$ is also be diagonalizable, as is $(A^2 + I)^2$.  It follows that the dimension of the nullspace of $(A^2 + I)^2$ will simply be the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$.

Remember that for any polynomial $p(t)$: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$.

Comment: How is $A$ diagonalizable? I am not sure whether there will be a 1 on the upper subdiagonal corresponding to the eigenvalue 0.

Comment: How does the dimension represent the multiplicity of the eigenvalue 0 instead of the other eigenvalues? How can the other multiplicities be represented as dimensions of nullspace of kernels?

Comment: You can tell that the matrix is diagonalizable by the minimal polynomial

Comment: In general, $\dim \ker (A-\lambda I)$ is the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$, and $\dim \ker(A-\lambda I)^n$ is the algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: When $A$ is diagonal, the algebraic and geometric multiplicities are the same.

Comment: Thanks. Then wouldn't the dim being asked for correspond to $\lambda = -1$ instead of $\lambda =0$? Will the exponent on $A+\lambda I$ always equal the multiplicity of $\lambda$?

Comment: The exponent on $(A + \lambda I)$ is the dimension of the space here; that doesn't apply to us since the matrix is diagonalizable.  $\dim \ker(A^2 - 1)$ is the multiplicity of the $0$ eigenvalue in the matrix $A^2 - I$, which is the same as the multiplicity of the $-1$ eigenvalue in $A^2$.  The multiplicity we should get is $2$, corresponding to the eigenvalues $\pm i$.